# Stylesheets and sqlite in Django/Openshift

Tags: python, django, sqlite, web, openshift

I've got an Openshift/Django issue:

I'm having difficulty getting stylesheets and my SQLite database working in Openshift. When attempting to access a page that uses the database, I get the following Django debug message: "no such table: mytable".  I get the same in rhc tail. Everything else appears to work.

My local file setup:

```
project
    project
        settings.py etc
    app
        normal django files and custom code here
    templates
        my templates are here
    static
        stylesheet is here
    mydatabase.db
```

For openshift, I modify the directory as follows:

```
openshift appname
    wsgi
        project
            project
                settings.py etc
            app
                normal django files and custom code here
            templates
                my templates are here
            static
                stylesheet is here (NOT WORKING)
            mydatabase.db (NOT WORKING)
```

Relevant bits of my setup.py file:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), os.pardir)
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
DATABASE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mydatabase.db')

...

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': DATABASE_PATH,
    }

...

STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Any ideas? It works fine when running locally.

Comment: What does this have to do with stylesheets?

Comment: The stylesheet doesn't load.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to checkout this blog post that goes over database configuration with django.
https://www.openshift.com/blogs/rapid-python-and-django-app-deployment-to-the-cloud-with-a-paas

Answer (score 0):

You are likely getting the "no such table" error because the table does not actually exist (or the database itself does not exist). You do not mention running `python manage.py migrate` (or for Django before version 1.7 `python manage.py syncdb`). Without having run that command the table will not be automatically created.

In your case I think the database does not exist. Every time you do a `git push` to openshift, all files in your account will be overwritten except the special folder referenced in `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`. This is the only folder that is guaranteed to be saved and persisted across updates. You may have gone through the trouble of running `migrate` before and then on your next `git push` the database was destroyed because you had it set to be stored in your project directory. To ensure that your sqlite database is persisted across pushes you should update your settings file as follows:

```
...

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR'], 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

...
```

On Openshift you need to use action hooks to run the `migrate` command. This is done by creating a folder called `.openshift/action_hooks` inside of your project folder. Within the folder create an executable bash script called `deploy`.

```
project
    .openshift
        action_hooks
            deploy
    project
    app
    templates
    static
```

The `deploy` file should contain the `migrate` and `collectstatic` commands. `migrate` will create the tables and `collectstatic` will copy all of the files in your `static` folder to the location specified in your settings under `STATIC_ROOT`. When running with DEBUG=false Django will not serve static files automatically. Openshift will use apache to serve the static files that are stored in `wsgi/static` so you should move the `static` folder up one level on Openshift and set `STATIC_ROOT` to point there. This should solve the stylesheet problem.

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'], 'wsgi/static')
```

**project/.openshift/action_hooks/deploy:**

```
#!/bin/bash
source $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/python/virtenv/bin/activate
cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR
echo "Executing 'python manage.py migrate'"
python manage.py migrate
echo "Executing 'python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'"
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```